# Why `Paths.get` method behaves different?

Tags: java, io

This code snippet print out `\\home\cay\`

```java
Path absolute = Paths.get("/", "home", "cay");
System.out.println(absolute);
```

However this print out `myprog\conf\user.properties`

```java
Path relative = Paths.get("myprog", "conf", "user.properties");
System.out.println(relative);
```

I have two questions:

1. Why there are two leading `\\`  in the first case?
2. Why there is a trailing `\` in the first case?

ps: I'm on a Windows system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first path was interpreted as [UNC path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/62e862f4-2a51-452e-8eeb-dc4ff5ee33cc) without an object name.

How it happened?
Diving into implementation, we can find the following:

[sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsPathParser.java)

```java
/**
  * Parses the given input as a Windows path.
  * 
  * @param   input - 1st case: '/\home\cay' ; 2nd case: 'myprog\conf\user.properties'
  * @param   requireToNormalize - true for both cases
  */
private static Result parse(String input, boolean requireToNormalize) {
  String root = "";
  WindowsPathType type = null;

  int len = input.length(); // 1st case: len = 10 , 2nd case: len = 27
  int off = 0;
  if (len > 1) {
    char c0 = input.charAt(0); // 1st case: c0 = '/' , 2nd case: c0 = 'm'
    char c1 = input.charAt(1); // 1st case: c1 = '\' , 2nd case: c1 = 'y'
    int next = 2;
    if (isSlash(c0) && isSlash(c1)) // this condition is true ONLY for 1st case
    {
       type = WindowsPathType.UNC;
       off = nextNonSlash(input, next, len); // 1st case: off = 2
       next = nextSlash(input, off, len);    // 1st case: next = 6
       if (off == next)
         throw new InvalidPathException(input, "UNC path is missing hostname");

       String host = input.substring(off, next); // 1st case: host = home
       off = nextNonSlash(input, next, len);     // 1st case: off = 7
       next = nextSlash(input, off, len);        // 1st case: next = 10
       if (off == next)
         throw new InvalidPathException(input, "UNC path is missing sharename");

       root = "\\\\" + host + "\\" + input.substring(off, next) + "\\"; // 1st case: root = \\home\cay\
       off = next; // 1st case: off = next = 10
    } else {
      if (isLetter(c0) && c1 == ':') { // this condition is false for 2nd case
        ...
      }
    }
 }
 if (off == 0) { // 1st case: off = 10, 2nd case: off = 0
    if (len > 0 && isSlash(input.charAt(0))) { // 2nd case: false
      type = WindowsPathType.DIRECTORY_RELATIVE;
      root = "\\";
    } else {
       type = WindowsPathType.RELATIVE;
    }
  }

  if (requireToNormalize) { // true for both cases
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    sb.append(root);
    /* 
      1st case: type = UNC, root = '\\home\cay\' , off = 10 , normalize(...) = '\\home\cay\'
      2nd case: type = RELATIVE, root = '' , off = 0 , normalize(...) = 'myprog\conf\user.properties'
     */
     return new Result(type, root, normalize(sb, input, off));
   } else {
     ...
   }
}

private static final boolean isSlash(char c) {
  return (c == '\\') || (c == '/');
}
```

And [sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathType](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsPathType.java)

So, for the first case you will have the **UNC** path type, for the second case the **RELATIVE** path type.

If you try to run the following snippet, you will get slightly different result (without final `\`, because the **object-name** will be present):

```java
Path uncPath = Paths.get("/", "my-host", "share", "obj");
System.out.println(uncPath); //  \\my-host\share\obj
```

If you try to run the following snippet:

```java
Path uncPath = Paths.get("/", "my-host");
```

you will get:

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: UNC path is missing sharename: /\my-host
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:118)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
```

Because according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/62e862f4-2a51-452e-8eeb-dc4ff5ee33cc):

> In a UNC path used to access files and directories in an SMB share, for example, object-name can be the name of a file or a directory. The **host-name**, **share-name**, and **object-name** are referred to as "pathname components" or "path components". *A valid UNC path consists of two or more path components.*

Comment: But why there is a trailing "\" in the first case and not in the second one?

Comment: Because of the checking isSlash(input.charAt(0))

Comment: @Bicheng, I have corrected my explanation. See my comments in the code. Hope it will help.

Answer (score -1):

Here the javadoc:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html

The implementation is system dependent because:

> The Path is obtained by invoking the getPath method of the default FileSystem.

It seems that you are on Windows and that `/` is converted to `\\`

I now tested your code on my Linux machine:

```java
Path absolute = Paths.get("/", "home", "cay");
System.out.println(absolute);
```

It prints `/home/cay` when i execute the above code.
This proves that the implementation is really system dependent.

**Update:**

Removed section that was wrong about the trailing slash. I now digged a bit deeper and the post from @SternK got updated, which is entirely correct.

So here my additions:

As shown in @SternK 's post, if the first character is a slash (on Windows), the path is considered to be of type `WindowsPathType.UNC` and that slash then gets replaced by `\\`. A UNC path consists of at least 2 levels whereas the first level represents the `host` and the second level the `share`, e.g. `\\hostname\sharename\`). Because there is no object name (or file path for that matter) present in `\\home\cay` a trailing slash is added so it becomes `\\home\cay\`. If you try it with `/home/cay/file1` you should get `\\home\cay\file1`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But why there is a trailing "\" in the first case?

Comment: Updated my post, have a look

Comment: I changed "cay" to "cay.txt", but it also returns with a trailing "\": \\home\cay.txt\